# Make a ::after element the same size and position as a flex child element

Tags: css

I am trying to add an efficient box-shadow to my flex elements by following this [article](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/).

Problem is it doesn't work, this is the minified [example](https://jsfiddle.net/cdx4kg6s/1/).

I've tried setting the `position: relative` on `nav`, but it just made the `::after` element the size of the whole navbar.

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a href="#">
      hello
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-center"></div>
  <div class="nav-right"></div>
</nav>
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 5rem;
  background-color: #402424;
  align-items: stretch;
}

nav a,
nav .brand {
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: #AFAFAF;
}

nav a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead,

Add to **nav a**

```
nav a{position:relative;}
```

also add to **nav a::after**

```
nav a::after{
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 5rem;
  background-color: #402424;
  align-items: stretch;
}

nav a,
nav .brand {
  text-decoration: none;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: #AFAFAF;
  position:relative;
}

nav a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

nav a:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-left,
.nav-center,
.nav-right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-left {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.nav-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-right {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-left">
    <a href="#">
      hello
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-center">
  
  </div>
  <div class="nav-right">
    World
  </div>
</nav>
```